# Multi-Language Site but the Date should be always in English

Tags: craft3, localization, datetime

with `{{ block.timeLimit|date('M d Y H:i')}}` i can get the real Date & Time in always the real Language from the Site. 
If the Page is German output is Dez, in English output is Dec.

How can i set the output of this Date always to en? Whatever language the Site has?

Thanks for every help!

Comment: Why can’t your date fields just be numeric?

Comment: That is not a option. I need it in english. I can't get it, is it that complicated? :D

Comment: You could make a twig filter to do this (or I might if there really is a need for this). From the little reading I’ve done so far, |date runs on PHPs datetime and messing with language requires locale changing.... etc. didn’t see a way to do this with |date

Answer (score 3):

I made a plugin to do this.

https://github.com/IndigoViking/Translitedated

Use it just like the |date filter (new filter is |dated) and pass it the date format and the locale you would like to use. In you case the locale would be 'en'.

Example from your question:

```
{{ block.timeLimit|dated('M d Y H:i', 'en') }}
```

This will always output an English date.

If you have any issues with it, just submit an issue via GitHub.

It's available via packagist so you can run

```
composer require indigoviking/translitedated
```

And it is in process to be approved on the plugin store (should only be a day or so. If you need more features/requests/or help with it, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Twig as well (without a plugin):

```
{% set formatter = create({ class: 'craft\\i18n\\Formatter', locale: 'en' }) %}
{{ formatter.asDate(now, 'php:j F Y') }}
```